# ScrollView Add SubView in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, uiscrollview, scrollview

I want to try add a view form on scroll view but view don't fully added on scroll view's frame, my code is:

```
import UIKit

class AddIncomeVC: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet var views: UIView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        scrollView.contentSize = views.frame.size
        scrollView.addSubview(views)

    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        views.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: scrollView.frame.size.width, height: scrollView.frame.size.height)
    }

}
```

[image]

Thanks,

Comment: just change one line views.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: scrollView.frame.size.width, height: scrollView.frame.size.height) this to 

views.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: scrollView.bounds.width, height: scrollView.bounds.hight)

Comment: @Himanshu, getting same issue,

Comment: brother then use constrain its batter to manage your screen if you need then i will tell you

Comment: Ok, how to use?

Comment: give constrain to your scrollview 4 size fix with your main view . then inside scrollview give constrain 4 size fix to your scrollview and fix hight of your subview and then give your view to scrollview equal width and just create one IBoutlet of your subview hight constrain and mange it your problem solve

Comment: if you are not able to give constrain then tell me i just manage it send me your project .

Comment: @Himanshu, thanks for your support

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131017/discussion-between-himanshu-moradiya-and-raj-joshi).

Answer (score 3):

Edit line

`views.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: scrollView.frame.size.width, height: scrollView.frame.size.height)`

to

`views.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: scrollView.contentSize.width, height: scrollView.contentSize.height)`

Comment: Having same problem

Comment: Did you set constraints in storyboard for scrollView?

Comment: This line  scrollView.contentSize = views.frame.size in viewDidLoad is wrong

Comment: if you want to set view size as scrollView content size do that in viewDidLayoutSubViews. At the time of viewDidLoad storyboard constraints  will not be taken

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

I get solved my issue with this code:

```
import UIKit

class AddIncomeVC: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet var views: UIView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        scrollView.contentSize = views.frame.size
        scrollView.addSubview(views)


    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        views.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height)

    }

}
```

Thanks all for giving valuable time for my question.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is: At view did load, your constraints are not updated to the new display sizes. 
I believe that your problem occurs because you are running the app using a simulator with different size from your storyboard... a bigger size (storyboard using iPhone SE and running at iphone 6 simulator, for example).

At View did Load, your view already exists, its true... but its constraints still have iphone SE sizes.

So, at view did load you are setting the content size (that you want with an iphone6 screen size) equal to storyboard view size (that still an iphone SE screen size).

Your solution works well. After the iOS layout all subviews, the constraints are updated to the new screen sizes, maintaining its proportions. 
At viewDidLayoutSubviews the "view" already have the correct constraint values... So, the view has iphone6 screen sizes, and you could set the frame with the right