# Scrollview in xib custom view to fit with multiple width

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiscrollview, xib

Currently, I am implementing custom view from a xib with `Content View` size set to `Freeform`. Here is my Content View hierarchy

[image: Content View hierarchy]

Although the Content View is Freeform, I set the width to 375, which is the same width with iPhone 8. Then I create a custom UIView file

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    commonInit()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    commonInit()
}

private func commonInit() {
    Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("DetailsWeather", owner: self, options: nil)
    addSubview(contentView)
    contentView.frame = self.bounds
    contentView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]

}
```

After that, I set the xib `File’s Owner` custom class name to the same custom UIView file above. Then I implement it into `Main.storyboard` by adding a UIView, set constrains properly and give it the custom class name the same with `File’s Owner`

When running iPhone 8, everything is perfect but switching to smaller device like iPhone 5s, I notice my scroll view now have horizontal scroll. Contrast with iPhone 5s, the bigger screen device like iPhone 8+, my scroll view now lost a bit of to the right side.

[image: Notice the labels does not align with the clock which is center on iP8+ anymore]
Notice the labels does not align with the clock which is center on iP8+ anymore

So I tried to remove the scroll view and everything work normal across devices. So from these, I was thinking the scroll view must messed up my custom view. Then I do some self research and found out these topics.

[How to update constraints after adding UIView from xib on UIScrollView in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45800609/how-to-update-constraints-after-adding-uiview-from-xib-on-uiscrollview-in-swift)

[ScrollView Add SubView in swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41236473/scrollview-add-subview-in-swift-3)

I tried their solution and modified to fit my situation but none of them seem to work with me. So my question is, is there a way to make Content View of a xib file to fit every width?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just solved today, feels great tbh

1. Remove all above step, just keep the IBOutlet in your custom UIView file
2. Remove `File’s Owner` custom class name and replace `Content View` custom class name to the same name with your custom UIView
3. Add UIView into your `Main.storyboard`, my case is ScrollView. Add all required constrains (duh)
4. Add IBOutlet for the ScrollView like this `@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!`
5. Navigate to your View Controller file
6. `let alohaView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("Feature", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as? FeatureView` with `Feature` is your xib file and `FeatureView` is your custom UIView file control that xib file
7. Add `alohaView?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 500)` notice I hardcode the 500 height, will work more on this
8. `scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: (alohaView?.frame.size.height)!)`
9. `scrollView.addSubview(alohaView!)` add the custom view back to scroll view